# Linearization method or Lyapunov function - example

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

I have to find a proper Lyapunov function or use the linearization method, for the following system:

$\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
x'=-x-y+xy \\
y'=x-y+x^2+y^2 \\
\end{array} \right.$

So first of all I tried a linearization. I've found out that $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is a solution of our system. I build a Jacobian matrix, substitute with above point, and find the characteristic polynomial which is $\lambda^2+2\lambda+2=0$, hence $\lambda_1=-1-i$ and $\lambda_2=-1+i$. We have that $Re \lambda <0$, so the zero solution is asymptotically stable. Am I right?

I've also tried traditionally the Lyapunov function $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ ... but isn't the above enough?

Phase portrait:

[image]

Please check my solution, and if anything is wrong - correct me. I would also need help with Lyapunov function in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A complete solution follows as :**

For the equilibria :

$$\begin{cases} -x-y+xy &= 0 \\ x-y + x^2+y^2 &= 0 \end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} x=y/(y-1) \\ y/(y-1) - y + y^2/(y-1)^2 + y^2 = 0  \end{cases}$$

$$\implies  $$

$$y(y-1) - y(y-1)^2 + y^2 + y^2(y-1)^2 = 0$$

$$\Rightarrow $$

$$y\big[y^3-3y^2+5y-2\big] = 0$$

This yields the following two stationary points :

$$\begin{cases} x = 0 \\ y = 0 \end{cases} \quad \text{and} \quad \begin{cases} x= -1.20557 \\ y = 0.546602\end{cases} $$

Thus, the origin $O(0,0)$ and the point $A(-1.20557, 0.546602)$ are stationary points for the given system of ODEs.

The linearization matrix is the Jacobian of the system :

$$J(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} -1 + y & -1+x \\ 1+2x & -1+2y  \end{bmatrix}$$

The linearization matrix around the stationary point, namely the origion $O(0,0)$, is :

$$J(0,0) = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

with $\det(J(0,0)) \neq 0$, thus the origin $O(0,0)$ is a non-hyperbolic stationary point for the given system of ODEs.

The eigenvalues of the linearization matrix around the origin are :

$$\det(J(0,0) - \lambda I) = 0 \Rightarrow \begin{vmatrix} -1 - \lambda & -1 \\ 1 & -1-\lambda \end{vmatrix} = 0 \Rightarrow (\lambda +1)^2+1 = 0 \Leftrightarrow \lambda = -1 \pm i$$

Noting that $\Re\{\lambda\} = -1 < 0$, this tells us that the origin $O(0,0)$ is an asymptotically stable focus/spiral point. This is a strong and sufficient conclusion and no further testing is needed.

The same approach shall be carried out for the point $A$. Again, you will have a strong and sufficient conclusion which means no further testing is needed.

Forming a stream plot (phase portrait) for our system of ODEs :

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  \qquad \qquad  $[image]

From the stream plot, we see the asymptotic stability of the origin, forming a spiral (focus). Also, the point $A$ seems to be an unstable saddle point, judging from its nature.

---

Personally, I think that the exercise should want you to study the origin only, as finding the solution to the other point is not easy and also computing all the stuff is also messy (its exact form isn't a "nice" fraction).

---

**Alternative :** An alternate approach would be via a Lyapunov test function. This problem though would need a kind of weird one, since none of the "classic" ones seem to work.

Comment: According to Lyapunov function: $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ hence after some simplifications $V'(x,y)=-2(x^2+y^2)+4y(x^2+y^2)=$ from that I concluded that -2<0 so the solution is asymptotically stable :p. I'm aware that it might be wrong, but it was on my colloquium. That's also why I haven't found your $A$ point.

Comment: @MacAbra Hi, how did you conclude that -2<0 from $\dot{V}$ ?

Comment: I have a really small knowledge about Lyapunov functions. Just tried to copy other solutions from my textbooks or this forum. Finding them doesn't seem to be as easy as the first Lyapunov method.

Comment: @MacAbra : It should be $\dot V=-2V+2y(2x^2+y^2)$ and then one could use that $2y(2x^2+y^2)=O(V^{3/2})$.

Comment: It is : $\dot{V}(x,y) = V_x \cdot x' + V_y \cdot y'$. For $V(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ and your given system of ODEs, it is : $$\dot{V}(x,y) =  2y^3 + 4x^2y-2x^2-2y^2$$ which means you cannot conclude about its sign. As mentioned by LutzL though, some analysis methods could help you work around with it.

Comment: Your answer is fine, but I have one objection: the **standard** definition of a hyperbolic equilibrium is that the Jacobian matrix has no eigenvalues with zero real part. So, $O(0,0)$ **is a hyperbolic** equilibrium (however, not a saddle).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to consider all the equilibrium points. The set of equilibrium points is given by the solutions of

$$
x+y-xy= 0\\
x-y+x^2+y^2=0
$$

with the real solutions $(0,0)$ and $(-1.20557,0.546602)$ The next step is their qualification. Local linearization, Jacobian eigenvalues, etc. What about possible limit cycles? The dynamic system seems to be asymptotically stable near the origin. How to calculate it's attraction  basin?

[image]

Comment: Limit cycles and attraction basin isn't required in this exercise.